# Get previous and next row from rows selected with (WHERE) conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, row

For example I have this statement:

```
my name is Joseph and my father's name is Brian
```

This statement is split by word, like this table:

| ID | word |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | my |
| 2 | name |
| 3 | is |
| 4 | Joseph |
| 5 | and |
| 6 | my |
| 7 | father's |
| 8 | name |
| 9 | is |
| 10 | Brian |

I want to get previous and next word of each word

For example I want to get previous and next word of "name":

| my | name | is |
| --- | --- | --- |
| father's | name | is |

How could I get this result?

Comment: Is there any gaps in your ids?

Comment: What database are you using?  What version of that database are you using?  SQL is a language but almost every database has a slightly different dialect of SQL that it supports.  This sort of thing is much easier when you're using a database that supports analytic functions like `lead` and `lag`.

Comment: i use SQL 2012, support LAG and LEAD, but i want take result for 5 million word quickly, its important to take result very fast in my program

Answer (score 87, accepted):

you didn't specify your DBMS, so the following is ANSI SQL:

```
select prev_word, word, next_word
from (
    select id, 
           lag(word) over (order by id) as prev_word,
           word,
           lead(word) over (order by id) as next_word
    from words
) as t
where word = 'name';
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7639e/1

Comment: with this code, in inner select statement the whole rows of table are combine and in outer: select rows with same word, if i want take only one word all of table words are combined and then select one of them...

Comment: its ok, but i have over 100 milion records, and time to take result is very important, can i improve performance of this code

Comment: @mahdiyousefi: please create a new question for that.

Answer (score 34):

Why did no-body give the simple answer?

```
SELECT LAG(word) OVER ( ORDER BY ID ) AS PreviousWord ,
       word ,
       LEAD(word) OVER ( ORDER BY ID ) AS NextWord
FROM   words;
```

Comment: You're failing to restrict results to next/previous of a particular word. The accepted answer has a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 12):

Without subqueries:

```
SELECT a.word 
FROM my_table AS a
JOIN my_table AS b 
ON b.word = 'name' AND abs(a.id - b.id) <= 1
ORDER BY a.id
```

Comment: this will not work if there are gaps in the id sequence

Comment: @t-clausen.dk op said the table was created from splitting a sentence, so there shoudn't be any gap

Comment: additional column ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) will do the trick then

Answer (score 4):

Use `Join` to get the expected result for `SQL Server 2005` plus.

```
    create table words (id integer, word varchar(20));

    insert into words
    values
    (1 ,'my'),
    (2 ,'name'),
    (3 ,'is'),
    (4 ,'joseph'),
    (5 ,'and'),
    (6 ,'my'),
    (7 ,'father'),
    (8 ,'name'),
    (9 ,'is'),
    (10,'brian');

SELECT A.Id ,  C.word AS PrevName , 
               A.word AS CurName , 
               B.word AS NxtName 
FROM words AS A
LEFT JOIN words AS B ON A.Id = B.Id - 1
LEFT JOIN words AS C ON A.Id = C.Id + 1
WHERE A.Word = 'name'
```

**Result:**

[image]

[Fiddler Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7639e/7)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM   tablename a
WHERE  ID IN(SELECT ID - 1
             FROM   tablename 
             WHERE  word = 'name') -- will fetch previous rows of word `name` 
        OR ID IN(SELECT ID + 1
                 FROM   tablename 
                 WHERE  word = 'name') -- will fetch next rows of word `name`
        OR word = 'name' -- to fetch the rows where word = `name`
```

Comment: Its ok, but i have more than 100 milion records, and time to take result is very important, can i improve performance of code?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach, if you want the selects to be fast. It takes a bit of preparation work.

- Create a new column (e.g. "phrase") in the database that will contain the words
  you want. (i.e. the previous, the current and next).
- Write a trigger that on insert appends the new word to the previous
  row's phrase and prepends the previous row's word to the new row's word and fills
  phrase.
- If the individual words can change, you'll need a trigger on update to keep the phrase in sync.

Then just select the phrase. You get much better speed, but at the cost of extra storage and slower insert and harder maintainability. Obviously you have to update the phrase column for the existing records, but you have the SQL to do that in the other answers.