# Get before and after rows of selected rows with specific condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row

my application get books and insert each word of this books to database, it may have more than 100 million words in books and inserted to database.
Now I want get specific word with previous and next words.
time to get result is very important.

> for example : "The book words insert here in this table..."

```
------------------------------
|      ID      |    word     |
------------------------------
|       1      |     the     |
|       2      |     book    |
|       3      |     words   |
|       4      |     insert  |
|       5      |     here    |
|       6      |     in      |
|       7      |     this    |
|       8      |     table   |
|       .      |     .       |
|       .      |     .       |
|       .      |     .       |
------------------------------
```

or in other example:

```
------------------------------
|      ID      |    word     |
------------------------------
|       1      |     my      |
|       2      |     name    |
|       3      |     is      |
|       4      |     joseph  |
|       5      |     and     |
|       6      |     my      |
|       7      |     father  |
|       8      |    name     |
|       9      |     is      |
|       10     |    brian    |
------------------------------
```

I want to get previous and next value of same word

For example I want get previous and next word of "name":

```
--------------------------
|   my    |  name  |  is |
--------------------------
|  father |  name  |  is |
--------------------------
```

in other related post friends write codes but this code take long time to get result, I want get the result table quickly:

related post: [question] [Get previous and next row from rows selected with (WHERE) conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086377/get-previous-and-next-row-from-rows-selected-with-where-conditions)

Comment: how often do you plan to run the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create index on my words column and set this code to get result quickly:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(SELECT * FROM WordsTable WHERE word=N'Name')
SELECT          
    t2.word AS previousWord,
    t1.word,
    t3.word AS nextWord
FROM
    WordsTable AS t2,
    CTE AS t1,
    WordsTable AS t3
WHERE
    (t2.ID + 1)= t1.ID AND
    (t3.ID - 1) = t1.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Join` to get the expected result for `SQL Server 2005` plus.

```
    create table words (id integer, word varchar(20));

    insert into words
    values
    (1 ,'my'),
    (2 ,'name'),
    (3 ,'is'),
    (4 ,'joseph'),
    (5 ,'and'),
    (6 ,'my'),
    (7 ,'father'),
    (8 ,'name'),
    (9 ,'is'),
    (10,'brian');

SELECT A.Id ,  C.word AS PrevName , 
               A.word AS CurName , 
               B.word AS NxtName 
FROM words AS A
LEFT JOIN words AS B ON A.Id = B.Id - 1
LEFT JOIN words AS C ON A.Id = C.Id + 1
WHERE A.Word = 'name'
```

**Result:**

[image]

[Fiddler Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/7639e/7)