# Count rows that follows other rows in a single table both restricted with a where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

I have a table that contains several millions of events. The primary key is composed of three columns:

- Time DateTime
- user (bigint)
- context (varchar(50))

I have another column with a value (nvarchar(max))

I need to count rows restricted on

> context = 'somecontext' and value = 'value2'

that follows **in time** rows restricted on

> context = 'somecontext' and value = 'value1'

for the same user.

For Example with the following records:

**Time** **user** **context** **value**

2019-02-22 *14:56:57*.710 359586015014836 somecontext   value1

2019-02-22 *15:13:42*.887   359586015014836 somecontext value2 <------ Need to count this rows only.

It is "recorded" 15 min after the first one and the user and context are the same.

I have seen other similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/169233/15186) or [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27086377/15186).

Should I make a JOIN on the same table? Use subqueries? may be a CTE? I'm concerned about performance that should be optimal.

The idea would be to use query features available in this version of the DB engine.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "that follows in time rows restricted on"? Do you want to count the rows where, for exampe, there is no rows between 20000101, 1,  'somecontext' , 'value1' and 20000102, 1,  'somecontext' , 'value2' filtered by user ordered by time?

Comment: I've updated my question. Is it more clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the example that I made in comment is what you want than you can use the following code
assuming that you want to select all the rows `where context = 'c1'`, current `value = 'v1'`, next value = 'v3' if `ordered by time`:

```
declare @t table
(
    Time_ DateTime,
    user_ bigint,
    context varchar(50),
    value_ varchar(50)
);

insert into @t values
('20000101', 1, 'c1', 'v1'),
('20000102', 1, 'c2', 'v3'),
('20000103', 1, 'c1', 'v3'),
('20000104', 2, 'c1', 'v1'),
('20000105', 2, 'c1', 'v4'),
('20000106', 2, 'c1', 'v2');

with cte as
(
select *, 
       lead(value_) over(partition by user_ order by time_) as next_value
from @t
where context = 'c1' 
)

select *
from cte
where next_value = 'v3';
```

Comment: That's exactly it. Thank you. There's just a typo in the last restriction on the next_value that should read 'v3' :)